# How do I filter tabs before injecting script only to user defined URLs patterns?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I do this without writing all that wheel by myself?

How do I filter out tabs by a pattern like this: "*.google.com", "*something.*.com" before injecting Script from background script?

Is there a solution or library for this?

```
regexpr=new RegExp(url.replace(/^[\./ ]*|[/. ]*$/gi,"").replace(/[\"'<>()`~{}!#@?%&+;,]/gi,"").replace(/\*/gi,"[^\.]*").replace(/\//gi,"\\/").replace(/\./gi,"\\.").replace(/^http/gi,"^http"))
```

How to do blacklisting/whitelisting in extensions right?

Comment: It not clear what the problem is. In the simplest case all you need is one `if` that checks the URL against the regexp in chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted and then use chrome.tabs.executeScript

Comment: no, I am asking do I really need to filter it by myself, is there some method to get it done automatically? If so, how exactly I can generate regex sequences for every pattern user can enter inside option page?

Comment: I can have something like https://*.google.com or https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab or https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=* . How exactly do I match it with regex? Isn't there any library for this?

Comment: I would use chrome.declarativeContent